# Remove slash from string in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to remove "\" from below string

```
{\"MACAddress\":\"74:5E:78\",\"DeviceName\":\"Connected_Device\"}
```

Response should be

```
{"MACAddress":"74:5E:78","DeviceName":"Connected_Device"}
```

I need to check if string includes "\n",i need to add validation to remove "\"

Can you please help how to handle this in rails?

Currently i am using httpparty below code

```
        reqType = params['reqType']
         payLoadData = params['payLoadData']

        p "PAYLOAD DATA-------------- #{payLoadData}"
        if reqType == "post"
          start = Time.now
        url=params['url']
        body_param= device 
        p "payLoadData-------------- #{body_param}"

        response = HTTParty.post(url,
         :body => body_param,
         :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json','User-Agent'=> 'Auto',"Authorization" => 'Basic=='})
        result_hash["response"].push({"body": response.body.to_s, "response_time": response_time.to_s})
        result_hash["status"].push(response.code)
```

Comment: Your string looks like a valid JSON hash. Where does it come from? Why do you need to manipulate it? I parsiing and working with a Ruby hash an option?

Comment: I am getting this response from ajax and passing as payLoadData = params['payLoadData'].This payload data value coming with \.

Comment: How do you know the string has escaped double quotes? Are you sure you're not seeing `String#inspect` output? Compare `puts '"string"'` with `puts '"string"'.inspect` to see the difference between what the string actually contains and how you might see it.

Comment: Would you give specific json which both includes the `\n` characters and other `\`, and its expected output?  Solely from your explanation I cannot figure out exact string processing you are looking for.

Comment: If `response.body` is already JSON, then you don't want to do `response.body.to_s`.

Comment: You json variable gives an error in my ruby compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.parse("{\"MACAddress\":\"74:5E:78\",\"DeviceName\":\"Connected_Device\"}")`

It should do the trick

Comment: Thanks.But i am getting response from ajax and passing like  payLoadData = params['payLoadData'].This payload data coming with \ value

Comment: I have tried  this payLoadData.gsub!(/\"/, '\'').But getting this {'MACAddress':'74:5E:78','DeviceName':'Connected_Device'}

Comment: @SubashiniRaja That suggests that you don't have `\"` in the string, just `"` that are being represented as `\"` by `String#inspect` or similar.

Comment: @SubashiniRaja there's something else you're doing incorrectly. You should not need to do `gsub` anywhere at all for this.

Answer (score 1):

The response that you get from your Ajax call is a hash in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

Just use a JSON parser to translate the JSON string into a Ruby hash:

```
require 'json'

pay_load = params['payLoadData']
device = JSON.parse(pay_load)

device['MACAddress']
#=> "74:5E:78"
device['DeviceName']
#=> "Connected_Device"
```

When you just want to output the hash a simple `puts device` or a `<%= device %>` (depending on your context) should work. Because in both cases `to_s` is called on the hash internally.

Comment: Thanks.I am using httparty.Payload data contain any json value.It may vary.I have updated content. Please check.

Comment: That is extremely weird because HTTParty would automatically parse JSON responses into Ruby hashes. Is it possible that the API returns parts of its response multiple times? This might happen when the payload was sent as JSON to the API and the API just sends it back in another JSON structure but didn't care about the payloads internal format in the first place. What API do you use? Who does the plain JSON response look like before parsing?

Comment: Btw if the JSON can _contain any JSON value_ how do you plan to use that in your application? Just print as the JSON string?

Comment: Yes.Printing as Json value.Before it was working fine.Now i am seeing this issue.

Comment: I just updated my answer: A simple `puts device` or a `<%= device %>` (depending on where and how you want to print that value) should work.